# Handling large strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, parameters, parameter-passing

I've made a function in Javascript to encrypt/encode a string before passing it to another page.

The problem is that it isn't able to handle (editing, passing, returning etc...) large strings. Is there a way to do this in Javascript?

**Note:** At the moment I do not use jQuery because I think it's too complicated.

Here's some example code:

```
    function replaceAt(str, index, character) {
        return str.substr(0, index) + character + str.substr(index+character.length);
    }

    function EncryptURL(inputstring) {
        var output = inputstring;
        for(var i=0; i<output.length; i++) {
            output = replaceAt(output, i, String.fromCharCode(output.charCodeAt(i) + 5));
        }
        return output;
    }
```

The function simply shifts each character 5 characters to the right. Ex: A -> F

**Example input:** `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`

**Output:** `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK`

When inputting a large string the characters are getting messed up somewhere around index 58. No errors.

EDIT:

The page language is HTML by the way.

***More code:***

```
    function DoubleEncryptURLToURLBox() {
        var namesarraystr = document.varreciever.variab.value; //Names separated by '_'. Example: Vincent_Jack_Felix_Simon_Jonathan_Monica_Eva_Tony_Anna
        var output = ""; output = namesarraystr;
        var i = 0;

        if(output.indexOf("?") != -1) {
            i = output.indexOf("?") + 1;
            output = output.substring(output.indexOf("?"));

            for(i = i; i<output.length; i++) {
                output = replaceAt(output, i, String.fromCharCode(output.charCodeAt(i) + 5));
            }
            output = "http://www.[website].com/redirect.html?" + EncryptURL(("nrc" + output)); //+ EncryptURL("?true");
        }

        document.getElementById("SettingsDiv").style.height = "auto";
        document.getElementById("CopyURLBox").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("CopyURLBox").value = output;
    }
```

Sorry about it being long.

Comment: It works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/Lnsw5svw/

Comment: The code in your link doesn't output anything to me? :I

Comment: Are you checking the console? (Ctrl shift I in Chrome)

Comment: I modified a bit the input from Stuart, it works bro. I am using a humoungusly large string

http://jsfiddle.net/Lnsw5svw/2/

And yes, check the js console to see the output.

Comment: I just tried it on another webpage that I created. There it works fine too, still I am using the same code. Something is wrong with the initial page then...

Comment: Some other part of your code must be going wrong - you may want to paste more code.

Comment: @Stuart Is there a limit how many loops can be used in one function? Because I have one loop in the initial function and then right after that it executes `EncryptURL()`. I will post the code in a few sec...

Comment: You are creating and concatenating strings at each iteration. I suggest splitting the string to an array characters, modifying each character, and then joining it to a string again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new code you posted you do this:

```
output = output.substring(output.indexOf("?"));
```

which discards the part of the string before the question mark.

You then encode the characters from `i` (the original position of the question mark) to the end of the string, ignoring the fact that the characters before the question mark have already been discarded.

You then call `EncryptURL` on the whole string.

So the part of the string from `i` to the end gets encrypted twice while the rest gets encrypted only once.

Anyway, an easier way would be simply to call the `encryptURL` function twice:

```
function encryptURL(input) {
    var output = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        output += String.fromCharCode(input.charCodeAt(i) + 5);
    }
    return output;
}

function doubleEncryptToURLBox() {
    var output = document.varreciever.variab.value; //Names separated by '_'. Example: Vincent_Jack_Felix_Simon_Jonathan_Monica_Eva_Tony_Anna
    if (output.indexOf("?") != -1) {
        output = output.substring(output.indexOf("?") + 1);
        output = "http://www.[website].com/redirect.html?" + 
            encryptURL('nrc' + encryptURL(output));
    }
    document.getElementById("SettingsDiv").style.height = "auto";
    document.getElementById("CopyURLBox").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("CopyURLBox").value = output;
}
```

Comment: Heh, just saw that and your post at the same time. Silly me. Thanks alot!

Comment: The thing is that I used DoubleEncryptURLToBox() first, and after that I created EncryptURL(). So I forgot to remove the encrypt code in the original function. :)